# Does "use of SHA-256 in cryptography" imply use of SHA-256 both in HMAC and DH key exchange, assuming these are the only uses of hash in system?

Tags: diffie-hellman, key-exchange, hmac, sha-256

I am beginner to Cryptography. And recently I came across the requirement like "use of SHA-256 in cryptography".

Does "use of SHA-256 in cryptography" imply use of SHA-256 both in HMAC and DH key exchange, assuming these are the only uses of hash in system?

I would be very thankful if people can provide their views.

**EDIT**

To explain the situation…

There is requirement to use SHA-256 in our product (embedded system) for SSH. As far I understand, SHA-256 is used in two places: one in diffie hellman key exchange and another in HMAC calculation. The confusion is – if we are planning to use SHA-256, then shall we use it in both the places or only for HMAC calculation?

Comment: in all the things

Comment: Is it ok to use SHA1 in diffie hellman key exchange and SHA-256 in HMAC ??

Comment: SHA-256 is just a digest algorithm. It can be used wherever a digest can be used. There's no such term as "use of SHA-256 in cryptography", it's just a sentence.

Comment: For a useful answer, we need more context; like, the whole sentence; or if there there is some implicit requirement like: _give some_ use of SHA-256 in cryptography; or if it is the title of some other material.

Comment: @fgrieu : There is requirement to use SHA-256 in our product (embedded system) for SSH. As far I understand, SHA-256 is used in two places, one in diffie hellman key exchange and another in HMAC calculation. The confusion is if we are planning to use SHA-256 then shall we use it in both the places or only for HMAC calculation. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: So the real question would be: From a certification standpoint, does " _use of SHA-256 in cryptography_ " imply use of SHA-256 both in HMAC and DH key exchange, assuming these are the only uses of a hash in the system? It that's correct, I think an update of the text of the question would help, although I would not [touch that with a $2^4$ foot pole](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/not_touch_something_with_a_ten_foot_pole); except perhaps with a terse: do it.